# How can I keep the same value?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables

I don't understand why the variables AUX and resultado dont return the same value that they was... I want to keep the value to return them to another class. Can you help me please?

My class is:

```
public class CriarConexao extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

      String response = "";
      try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            System.out.println("driver conectado");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/savetime", "root", "root");
            resultado = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ingresso");
            //ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while(rs.next()) {

                resultado = rs.getString(1);
            }

            AUX = resultado ;
            System.out.println("Auxiliar 1: " + AUX + " e " + resultado);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("ERRO: " + e.toString());
      }
    return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
        AUX = resultado ;
        System.out.println("Auxiliar 2: "+AUX + " e " + resultado);
    }
}
```

the logcat:

```
06-20 05:00:47.475: I/System.out(1592): Auxiliar 1: 1234 e 1234
06-20 05:00:47.475: I/System.out(1592): Auxiliar:  e
```

Comment: What is the value of         System.out.println("Auxiliar 2: "+AUX + " e " + resultado);

Comment: 06-20 05:00:47.475: I/System.out(1592): Auxiliar 2:  e

Comment: Apart from the output not matching the code, it is unclear where the proble is. AUX and resultado contain equal values, once "1234" and once "".

Comment: but I want the AUX and resultado keep them values 1234

Comment: Add this code: response=AUX; after this :AUX = resultado ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `doInBackground` function returning `response` variable value which is blank.So add `AUX` to `response`
 try this

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

      String response = "";
      try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            System.out.println("driver conectado");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/savetime", "root", "root");
            resultado = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ingresso");
            //ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while(rs.next()) {

                resultado = rs.getString(1);
            }

            AUX = resultado ;
            response = AUX;  // Add here
            System.out.println("Auxiliar 1: " + AUX + " e " + resultado);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("ERRO: " + e.toString());
      }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: @LucasYoshimura Happy to help,Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In your doInBackground method you are initializing a response string but you never assign either AUX or resultado to it so that's why in the postExecute resultado is empty (just because it has the same name doesn't make it the same variable). Since you are trying to return more than one String you need to adjust your asynctask to either return an array or map that contains the two values you want to return